# How do I identify the cause of a "no attribute was found" exception?

Tags: ios, ios6, restkit

I followed all the steps in the RestKit documentation for adding it to a project but when I try to start my app it stops at this line in `application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`:

```
entityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"_id"];
```

The code before that is:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyModel" ofType:@"momd"]];
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

// Init the Core Data stack
[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

NSPersistentStore __unused *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addInMemoryPersistentStore:&error];
NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Faild to add persistent store: %@", error);

[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Set the default shared store instance
[RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];

// Configure the object manager
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:9090"]];
objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];

RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Pool" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"id":         @"_id",
 @"about_url":  @"aboutURL",
 @"closed":     @"closed",
 @"created_on": @"createdOn"
}];
entityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"_id"];
```

The exception is getting thrown in RKEntityMapping.m on line 100 (`if (!attribute) [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"Invalid attribute '%@': no attribute was found for the given name in the '%@' entity.", attributeOrName, [entity name]];`) which is part of `RKArrayOfAttributesForEntityFromAttributesOrNames`.

When I `po [entity name]` it says "Pool" but I do have a Pool entity in my .xcdatamodeld.

Where else might I look for the cause of this error?

Comment: why `@[@"_id"]` and not `@[@"id"]`?

Comment: I originally had @[@"id"] but the key in the JSON is '_id' so I thought maybe that was the problem and changed that line.

Comment: what is the `id` property name in the `Pool` entity?

Comment: That was it.  I didn't have an id property in the Pool entity.  Thanks!  Add that as an answer so I can give you points for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `id` property to your `Pool` entity.
**Note:** naming a property `id` would work, but I would recommend changing it to something that is not an Objective-C keyword.